# Unable to solve integral of a summation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

> I want to integrate each datapoint in a 2D image $X$ over a disc, but i'm really unsure what to do with the summation term. Essentially, at each point $x_j$, we integrate a disc of radius $r$, centered at $x_i$. Note that $x_i = (a,b) \in X$ is a single data point, and the radius is fixed,

> \begin{align} \frac{1}{2N\pi r^2} \int_{\mathcal{B}(r,x_i)} \sum_{j=1}^N e^{-\frac{||X-x_j||_2^2}{2r^2}} \mathrm d^2X
> &=  \frac{1}{2\pi N r^2} \int_{\mathcal{B}(r,x_i)} \sum_{j=1}^N  e^{-\frac{||X-x_j||_2^2}{2r^2}} d^2X ~~~\\
>   & = \frac{1}{2\pi N r^2} \int_{\mathcal{B}(r,x_i)} \sum_{j=1}^N e^{-\frac{(x_1 - x_{j1})^2 + (x_2 - x_{j2})^2}{2r^2}} \mathrm dx_1\mathrm dx_2  ~~~~~~~~ ~~(1)
> \end{align}

Initially i thought each term in the sum is fixed, so I cancelled it out with $N$, and then i proceeded by converting to polar coordinates, i.e.  let $x_1 - x_{j1} = \rho \cos(\theta), x_2 - x_{j2} =\rho \sin(\theta),$ and $\mathrm dx_1\mathrm dx_2 = \rho \mathrm d\rho d\theta$, where $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\rho \in [0,r]$. Now, we get

\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{2\pi \rho^2}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\rho \exp\left(- \frac{\rho^2\sin^2(\theta)+\rho^2\cos^2(\theta)}{2\rho^2}\right)\rho \mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\rho &= \frac{1}{\rho^2} \int_0^\rho \rho \times \exp\left(- \frac{\rho^2}{2\rho^2}\right) \mathrm d\rho = 1 - e^{-\frac{1}{2}}
 \end{align*}

**BUT** i think the result of (1) should depend on the radius and $x_i$, and so **this method is wrong**, i should keep the summation in. (Maybe because, if a point is on the edge of $X$, then if you draw a disc around it, then the area will not all be in $X$, and so this is difficult to calculate...).

So the aim is to solve Equation (1), but how?

Comment: For clarification, if the simplified integral at the end was evaluated, would that work?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I edited the question. Polar coordinates went slightly wrong, i should keep the summation in. i.e. Aim is to solve Eq (1)

Comment: I'm not sure what eq (1) represents. Given one data point $x_i$, what precisely is the transformation you want to apply? ie. $x_i \to ?$

Comment: @Sal I just want to find the area of a disc centred at each datapoint in a 2D image, the function we are integrating is the density of said image. So i'm not really sure what the transformation will look like when it is integrated but it should depend on $x_i$ i think?

Comment: The area of a disc will simply be $\pi r^2$ unless the center of the disc is within $r$ of the boundary, in which case it's a circular segment. On the other hand, eq (1) instead looks like some sort of Gaussian averaging, which is why I ask what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: @Sal I'm defining the density of datapoints as a sum of Kroenke functions, which i then convolve with a Gaussian kernel. Then i want to integrate this function over a ball/disc which i centre at a pre-defined $x_i$

Answer (score 1):

You have a finite sum, so just switch the integral and summation operators by sum rule. After evaluating the line integral, just evaluate the sum of the integrals.

Comment: Switching the sum and integral will make no difference though, it still gives me the same problem